# I don't know the difference between 'The fact is that he doesn't know her.' and 'The fact is not that he knows her.'

Tags: meaning

Please see the sentences below.

1. 'The fact is that he doesn't know her.'
2. 'The fact is not that he knows her.'

What is the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: 2. The fact is not related to knowing her.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases there is a "fact".

The first one tells you what that fact is.  "He doesn't know her" is the fact.

The second tells you that the fact isn't "that he knows her".  The fact is something else.  But the second sentence doesn't tell you what the fact is.

Compare

> The name of the cat is Henry.

> The name of the cat is not George.

The first sentence tells you the name of the cat.  The second tells you what is not the name. It doesn't tell you what the name is.  The difference between these sentences is exactly analogous to the difference between your sentences.

Answer (score 1):

**Sentence 1**

`the fact = he doesn't know her.`

We know that the fact **is** that he doesn't know her.

**Sentence 2**

`the fact ≠ he knows her.`

We know that the fact **is not** that he knows her. But we don't know what the fact is.